# python script in docker creating locked files in volume

Tags: python, docker

I have a docker container with python and a mounted volume. The volume contains among other things, a python script and csv. I am copying the csv to a subdirectory inside that volume. It is working but file has root ownership and is locked and thus unusable. I need an unlocked file.

Outside of a docker, the python script does this, creates an unlocked file without any permissions issues. I tried changing the chmod. But it dont work.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.5

ADD entrypoint.sh entrypoint.sh
#RUN chmod 755 entrypoint.sh Also did not work
RUN chmod 777 entrypoint.sh 

ENTRYPOINT ./entrypoint.sh
```

Entrypoint:

```
cd volume
python copytest.py
```

copytest.py

```
import shutil

src = 'df_gent.csv'
dst = 'gent_copy.csv'

shutil.copy2(src, dst)
```

docker commands:

```
sudo docker build -t copytest .
docker run --name copy_test -v /home/user/Desktop/copytest-docker/:/volume -it copytest bash
```

Comment: What did you mean under *locked file*?

Comment: Everithing is root under docker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker container is running with root user. because of that after execution of copy command in copytest.py file "gent_copy.csv" will be own by root. which in tern behaving as lock.

You can create a user in Dockerfile same as on your system. so file will be copied with same user.

Please check below Dockerfile (replace XXXXXX with your local user).

```
FROM python:3.5
ARG local_user=XXXXXX
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash $local_user

ADD entrypoint.sh entrypoint.sh

RUN chown $local_user:$local_user entrypoint.sh
USER $local_user
RUN chmod 755 entrypoint.sh 

ENTRYPOINT ./entrypoint.sh
```